# Running cookbook on a client node

Tags: chef-recipe, chef-infra

I have a windows node configured .

I am using hosted server from opscode.com.
I have to run few cookbooks to chef client node. What is the procedure to this cookbook.

I am a newbie to this and not finding a proper link also.
Please help me with this solution.

edit:

I just need a link which explains running a cookbook on windows node. not able to find proper links...

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: is run_list of your node is empty? If it's empty, fill in by editing your node on chef server UI from opscode.com. please checkout this guide [Debug Recipes and chef-client Runs](http://docs.opscode.com/debug.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe is this [source](http://blog.onddo.com/blog/categories/tutorial/) all you need.

I hope this help you.